# search a number in the file and replace the number when program runs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner to python and i'm stuck in the assignment given to me.I have a file called file.h which has a certain information and a number in between something like this.

```
Working copy:C:/tmp
Repository root:svn:/localhost
VERSION_REV 8797
Schedule:normal
Date:13/12/2010
```

I need to write a python code so that whenever i run it should search for the number 8797 and replace it with a number stored in my variable i.e,x=8798.I tried like below,but not succeeded.

```
fout = open("path to\file\file.h","r+")
for line in open("path to\file\file.h"):
    line = line.replace("VERSION_REV %i","x")
    fout.write(line)
fout.close()
```

Sorry,I forgot to mention the i am using windows7 system.

Comment: Assuming you're on Unix, why not just use the command line? `sed -i "s/VERSION_REV [0-9]*/VERSION_REV 8979/g"` file

Comment: Also, just a quick response, the reason it did not work, is that `replace` is not a regex replace, or some other smart replace. It just replaces incidences of the first argument with th second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re
.....
line = re.sub(r'(?<=VERSION_REV )\d+', x, line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import re

data = open("path to\file\file.h","r+").read()
re.sub(r'VERSION_REV [0-9]+', 'VERSION_REV ' + newstr, data)
open("path to\file\file.h","w").write(data)
```

Without re

```
fout = open("path to\file\file.h","r+")
for line in open("path to\file\file.h"):
    if "VERSION_REV" in line:
        line = "VERSION_REV " + newstr
    fout.write(line)
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the below code..it did work for me.

```
fout=open("c:\path to file\file.h", "r+")
    for line in open("c:\path to file\file.h"):
        if "VERSION_REV" in line:
            line = "VERSION_REV " + "" + x + '\n' #where 'x' has new version _rev 8798
        fout.write(line)
    fout.close()
```